# Adverse effects of turning off "Find Implicit Dependencies"

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode has an option on schemes, "Find Implicit Dependencies" that I'd like to turn off for my project so that every time I do a clean, my Cocoapods directory doesn't get nuked as well causing a full-rebuild of code that hasn't changed.

Are there any adverse effects to turning this option off?

Comment: Why would this setting affect the Pods folder?

Comment: Because if it's turned off, the the pods won't ever get cleaned.